# Invoking Methods of another component in Observer Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

#### Question:

- Are there any techniques for communicating with methods of other components but still keep a "pure" Observer pattern ?
- If yes are they indicated/regularly-used or am I just overcomplicating stuff?

#### A practical example

Suppose I have an architecture with the following characteristics:

- System is a Word Processor app
- Many components, each with it's own purpose, e.g `KeypressDetector`, `Printer`, `DocumentRenderer`.
- Components modify/observe a single model, the `Document`
- The components thus "communicate" via this model observation/modification. The components don't know about each other in any other way.

If I'm not mistaken this is what the [Observer Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) is all about.

---

So here's one case where **there's a problem:**

- For component `Printer` to do it's job it needs some output from component `PagePreparator`.
- This is just one edge-case where component `PagePreparator` can't continuously update the model that is shared between the components because it involves heavy-computation. This involves just a single aspect of `PagePreparator`, e.g `PagePreparator.prepare() // takes a long time to run`.

So that's one case where It looks to me that I need to "break away" from this pure Observer setup and just *expose the method* of `PagePreparator` to `Printer` directly and call it explicitly from `Printer`. This will *couple* them explicitly together though.

Are there any techniques for keeping this Observer pattern exclusively and still be able to perform this kind of invocations?

**Possible solutions:**

- When `Printer` needs output it sets a flag on the model `Document`, e.g `updatePages` which is picked up by `PagePreparator`'s observers. `PagePreparator` then sets the output on the model `Document` which is picked up by `Printer`'s observer which proceeds to do it's job.
- Simply "breaking" the pattern and just expose `PagePreparator`'s method, `pagePreparator.prepare()` to `Printer` which can then explicitly call it.
- Dispatching an event from `Printer` which is picked up by `PagePreparator` which proceeds to set the value on the model `Document`, for `Printer` to pick it up.

Comment: For clarification, could you explain the print process? Presumably some method like `Printer.print` is called. Is that method called directly as the entry point? Is it called by `Document`? Is it hooked into an event which is raised by `Document`? And when you talk about "observing" currently, how does that work? Is it polling for changes to a property on some timer, or is it there some push mechanism like an event?

Comment: Oh, and another question, is the `PagePreparator`'s output used by anything other than the `Printer`?

Comment: @BenAaronson `Printer.print()` is called using an event. On your 2nd question, I don't really know what happens under the hood but it's just a regular data-binding mechanism (define a model and some observers for that model). As for your 2nd comment, yes `PagePreparator` output can be used for other components as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And what's the name of the specific language feature/framework/library/whatever you're using for the data-binding mechanism?

Comment: Thanks for the interest - Here: [Polymer data-binding explained](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option seems cleanest to me.   I frequently find myself making use of the [Event Aggregator Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) with applications containing isolated/disconnected modules communicating with each other via messages    (Another good page [Here](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/18/event-aggregator-andorvs-mediator-a-tale-of-two-patterns/)).

The pattern itself has become common at least in .NET with a lot of [examples](https://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2012/10/understanding-and-avoiding-memory-leaks.html) of 'generic' Event Aggregators around which should be able to translate into most languages.

The benefit of using messages to communicate between modules is that those modules remain decoupled; the cost however, is adding a layer of indirection.